# WordPress template file if else issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to show information on a template page I made in WordPress. I am trying to show posts with GPS data if they don't have a tag that says no-gps. I want to check which pages are missing the GPS data. Is there an easy way to do that? I'm thinking of using an if else statement to add a mark so that I can do a search for the pages in WordPress and manually add the missing GPS data. Any ideas are greatly appreciated though. How do I put the extra if else statement into the current if statement? Here's my code:

```
<?php if(!has_tag('no-gps')){
//the_tags();
echo '<span id="topgps"><strong>GPS</strong>: '; 
the_field("GPS");
echo '</span>';
} ?>
```

I want to write:

If there is a page that doesn't have the no-gps tag, with GPS data, show the value. This works now.

New bit: But if the GPS value is missing (no value at all) on a page that doesn't have the no-gps tag show a star ★ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code for the line with `the_field("GPS");` to:

```
$gps = get_field("GPS");
echo ($gps == '') ? '*' : $gps;
```

Comment: That works nicely. Thank you very much ScottM. What does the question mark and colon mean?

Comment: Update: I just found a page explaining it.

The Ternary Operator in PHP: Trinary–operator
2008-10-29
Its syntax is unusual at first, but it allows you to simplify more complex conditionals into one line statements.

The basic syntax of the ternary operator is:

(condition) ? 'true' : 'false';
In other words, PHP will evaluate the condition. If the condition is true, the first value–after the question mark–is returned. If the condition is false, the second value–after the colon–is returned.